# Angle of view based on height and distance to a determined object

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, angle

I'm trying to determine what angle of view is needed for a photo shoot so that I can determine which super telephoto lens to rent.

I'm photographing an object thats 2,600 meters across from an altitude of 500 meters and a distance on the ground of 7,000 meters.

Thanks

Comment: Telephoto lenses in my experience are rated by the length of a lens with an equivalent field of view attached to a 35-mm film camera body. An object of the size you state at the distance you state would be too large (or nearly too large) to capture in one image with a 100 mm lens. I think you would want a "shorter" lens, possibly 75 mm, at most 90 mm. I would hardly call that "super telephoto".

Answer (score 1):

distance $= \sqrt{500^2 + 7000^2} \approx 7018$

$2\tan \theta/2 = 2600/7018$ so $\tan \theta/2 \approx 0.185$, and $\theta/2 \approx 10.5$ degrees.

So your angle is about 21 degrees.